# CodeIgniter Framework: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing project using CodeIgniter framework and when I am running my project from Xampp it shows a 500 Internal Server Error. How to resolve Error 500 in CodeIgniter framework or Is this error of htaccess file?

```
SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
SetEnv PHP_VER 5

Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /aip

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^base.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(dishme\.com\.au)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|fonts|woff|ttf|eot|svg|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /aip/index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Block libwww-perl attacks
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
    RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>


# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```